# Assigning Multiple IPs to VM

Tags: networking, ip, linux-networking

I have created a VM in XenServer and I'm trying to assign three IPs (local and public) to it. Now as i read from google that I can create three files like ifcfg-eth0, ifcfg-eth0:0 and ifcfg-eth0:1 and change IPs in those files accordingly.

but my questions are:

1. If I create files with name ifcfg-eth0, ifcfg-eth1 and ifcfg-eth2, does it mean the same?
2. In Xencenter, I'm unable to see 3 IP's assigned to my VM but when I try to connect to my VM then I'm able to connect to it using different IPs... so what can be the issue with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple IP addresses is not the same thing as multiple interfaces.  Typically a single interface represents a single L2 network but can have multiple IP addresses (sometimes known as aliases or secondaries).  Multiple interfaces, in turn, generally correspond to distinct L2 networks.

Comment: However, common network configuration scripts make it difficult to have multiple IPs on one interface (whether you have one or many). I had to write my own new script in just to get it to work in Ubuntu.

Comment: It shouldn't be - just set up the /etc/network/interfaces file for eth0:0, eth0:1, etc for each alias as if it were a separate interface.

Comment: The scripts assume eth0:0 and eth0:1 are separate physical interfaces. This results in servers being taken down and started back up for each of these.

Comment: Yeah - that is annoying behavior.  Same situation with VLAN interfaces.